# Query Builder - how to chain paginate and keyBy?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This code gives me a paginated result-set, with additional info - number of total records, records per page, next page URL, etc. I want all that. But I'd also like to key the main resultset by ID rather than just getting a numerical array.

```
$laptops = Laptop::addJoins()->filterResults($request)->selectListCols()->paginate(50);
```

Is that possible? I tried chaining `keyBy('id')` on the end, which resulted in a keyed object, but without any of the pagination information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this to get collection keyed by `id`:

```
$laptopsCollection = $laptops->getCollection()->keyBy('id');
```

If you want to update collection used by paginator itself (so all pagination info is still accessible) do that afterwards:

```
$laptops->setCollection($laptopsCollection);
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks! I literally have no idea how I was supposed to know that, though. I can't see a getCollection() method anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: I usually `dd($laptops)` to see the class name `Paginator`, then open respective file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.php` and explore what goodies does it hide, often digging down through classes it extends, in this case `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php`.

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, but the above two statements seem to mess with the order of results. So if I have a sortBy() clause in my query builder, having the getCollection and setCollection methods above ruins the sort order. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: `getCollection` and `setCollection` do not modify collection in any way. Are you sure you don't mess with `$laptopsCollection` even after setting it? Also `sortBy` is a collection method, for query builder it should be `orderBy` (used before `paginate`). Other than that it is difficult to help without seeing the code, try to ask a separate question if you're still having trouble.